# API request works in PostMan but not in AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, api

I am trying to query the Reed jobs site to return Construction based jobs in Sheffield.

I have tried literally everything I can think of and posted numerous posts on here to try and get the code to work but to no avail.

Can someone please try the code themselves and see if they can work it out?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

````
<script>
$(function (){

  var $jobs = $('#jobs');

  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    async: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    username: '',
    beforeSend: function (xhr) { xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa('5afe0f90-3480-4d47-8206-3529815a610a:' )); },
    crossDomain: true,
    url: 'http://www.reed.co.uk/api/1.0/search?keywords=construction&location=sheffield',
    success: function(jobs) {
      $.each(jobs, function(i, job){
        $jobs.append('<li>' + job +'</li>')
      });
    },
  });

});

</script>

<ul id="jobs"></ul>```
````

Comment: Seems to reject the OPTIONS preflight request that is done by CORS. Will probably need to set up a proxy on your server

Comment: see my answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58167769/how-to-get-json-information-from-asp-net-core-web-app-using-javascript/58168368#58168368

Comment: @saifiqbal I have updated my question, can you try it for me?

Comment: @JakeFeeley ok. it needs username and pwd